# Rspec to upload file with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec, actiondispatch

I'm trying to write spec for testing upload function and the code implementation works as expected however when I tried to write spec I'm not able to figure out why the data conversation is failing during `JSON.parse`. [ Rails 5.X ]

Method

```
def upload
  #some validation
  begin
    puts params[:file]
    json = JSON.parse(params[:file].read)
    #rest of the validation
  rescue StandardError, JSON::ParserError, HttpServices::BadHttpResponseError
      flash[:style] = :error
  end
end
```

Spec:

```
describe "upload" do
  before do
    read = file_fixture("empy_details.json").read
    @file = Hash.new
    @file['emp'] = read #debugger > @file:{emp: [{"name":"Bob","key":"201","active":true}]}
  end

  it 'should upload' do
    post :upload, params: { :file => @file }, as: :json
    expect(flash[:style]).to eq(:success)
  end
end
```

The method `puts params[:file]` prints

```
{"emp"=>"[{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"key\":\"201\",\"active\":true}]\n"}
```

The `JSON.parse` fails at `convert_hashes_to_parameters(key, value)` method 
and `converted` gets value of `"[{"name":"Bob","key":"201","active":true}]"` before failing.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I am curious.  What is the debugger output of `params[:file].read`?

Comment: @TomAranda: it fails during .read and if I pass with just params[:file] I still get the same error. So I'm not sure if I have to format this to Action::Dispatcher object ? if so how.

Comment: Don't rescue StandardError - only rescue errors that you know what to do with. It will make debugging close to impossible as it will swallow a large amount of exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params[:file].read` was throwing exception when the file was passed through Rspec and I changed the controller method code to accommodate `params[:file]` instead.

```
def upload
  #some validation
  begin
    puts params[:file]
    if params[:file].respond_to?(:read)
      json = JSON.parse(params[:file].read)
    else
      json = JSON.parse(params[:file])
    end
    #rest of the validation
  rescue StandardError, JSON::ParserError, HttpServices::BadHttpResponseError
      flash[:style] = :error
  end
end
```